# How can I find time and space complexity of my solution

Tags: big-o

I am a beginner developer and still not very familiar with big O.

This is my solution of a leetcode problem, and I am not sure what my time and space complexity are for this solution.

```
    String s = "";
    String t = "";
    int back = 0;
    for (int i = S.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (S.charAt(i) == '#') {
            back++;
            continue;
        }
        if (back > 0) {
            back--;
            continue;
        }
        s += "" + S.charAt(i);
    }

    back = 0;
    for (int i = T.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (T.charAt(i) == '#') {
            back++;
            continue;
        }
        if (back > 0) {
            back--;
            continue;
        }
        t += "" + T.charAt(i);        
    }
    return s.equals(t);
    }
}
```

I presume my time complexity would be O(N) and have no idea what space complexity would be. If time complexity is not O(N), why is it not? Also, I think time complexity is not O(1) since I am storing input values in variables, but I am not sure about this either.

Answer (score 0):

**Time complexity**

Since you are running the loops, your complexity would be  **O(max(len(S), len(T)))**, more precisely **O(len(S) + len(T))**. So if you are assuming the lengths of the string as ***n***, your complexity would indeed be **O(n)**

**Space Complexity**

Space complexity is same as time complexity.